# Urllib2 returns html with empty body

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, request, urllib2

I'm curious why urllib2 module returns html with empty body. I'm sure that I'm putting there a correct url. The page does not show whole html code even if I try to view the source code using chrome. Here is one of those pages: `http://www.firmy.cz/Velkoobchod-a-vyroba/Vyrobci-papiroveho-a-polygrafickeho-zbozi/Nakladatele-a-vydavatele?geo=0`

How to solve this problem?

Here is a piece of my code but I think the problem is somewhere else according to chrome show the same code.

```
def getSoup(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    return soup
```

This code returns:

```
...
..
.. some head etc...
<meta content="!" name="fragment"/>
</head>
<body class="root" id="root"></body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the body is empty.

Comment: Any code? What are you doing?

Comment: I've attended a code into my question right now, but I think the problem is somewhere else. As I wrote, even a Chrome shows not whole source code.

Comment: Interesting, I seem to get some [code](http://pastebin.com/jFixSCu9). The body tag in the website itself has nothing in it for me too, possibly some JS is doing the magic.

Answer (score 0):

return only response.read() and parse it to remover newline character

```
url = "http://www.firmy.cz/Velkoobchod-a-vyroba/Vyrobci-papiroveho-a-polygrafickeho-zbozi/Nakladatele-a-vydavatele?geo=0"

def getSoup(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = response.read()
    response.close()
    return page

def do_whatever_you_want_with_response():
    page = getSoup(url)
    print page
    return page
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is an error: page = soup.replace('\n', '')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable It does not work.

Comment: My mistake, I had different code but it is still the same. I think you don't know what I mean. The problem is that it returns html without body, resp. body is empty which is impossible. I'm trying to get that body.

Comment: I am not sure if urllib2.urlopen(req) return any body method.
btw why you are looking at body function. response.read() method is returning the full html page. Just parse it and extract the html body part from it.

Comment: Thats the problem. If it returned full html, there would be for example a string "www.krasnapani.cz" as you can see on the page. But there is no string like that.

Comment: updated my answer. we need to close the url socket before printing the value. just added resonse.close() method.

Comment: @Milan:  FYI body part of the url is empty. It actually generating dynamically after page load. check this . view-source:http://www.firmy.cz/Velkoobchod-a-vyroba/Vyrobci-papiroveho-a-polygrafickeho-zbozi/Nakladatele-a-vydavatele?geo=0

Comment: Yes I know. Thats the problem. I'm searching for a way how to get that dynamicaly generated html.

Comment: no. you can not do that. that's total javascript stuff.
What's your actual requirement.